# Cannot be authenticated in Dusk using sanctum

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to make login page using Laravel sanctum and React.

I can login in my browser (can see 'authenticated' message), but I cannot login in Dusk.

To be exactly, **I can login once in Dusk but I'm not authenticated in next access**.

I cannot understand why it happened.

How can I be authenticated with Dusk using sanctum?

#### Environment

- Laravel 7.x
- laravel/sanctum ^2.6
- React 16.13.1

#### Login.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const axios = window.axios;

export default function Login(props) {
  const [strId, setStrId] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [hoge, setHoge] = useState('ini state');

  function normalUserLogin() {
    axios
      .get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
      .then((response) => {
        axios
          .post('/api/login', {
            strId: strId,
            password: password,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            setHoge(response.data);
            authCheck();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('Error happened.');
      });
  }

  function authCheck() {
    axios
      .get('/api/user/auth')
      .then((response) => {
        setHoge(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert('error happened getting auth information');
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row mt-5">
        <div className="col-12">
          <form>
            <label htmlFor="user-id" className="d-block">
              User ID
              <input
                name="user-id"
                id="user-id"
                className="d-block"
                value={strId}
                onChange={(e) => setStrId(e.target.value)}
              />
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="password" className="d-block">
              Password
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="off"
                className="d-block"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </label>
          </form>
          <button
            type="button"
            id="normal-login"
            className="btn btn-outline-success d-block"
            onClick={normalUserLogin}
          >
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-12">
        {hoge}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

#### MyCustomLoginController (app/Http/Api/LoginController.php)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    // routing is '/api/login'
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $str_id = $request->input('strId');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $credentials = compact('str_id', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $hoge = Auth::check() ? 'OK' : 'NG';
            // $hoge is OK in dusk.
            return response($hoge);
        } else {
            return response('Cannot Authenticated', 401);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Auth check action

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // routing is '/api/user/auth'
    public function auth(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user) {
            $params = User::getParamsForApp($user->str_id);
            // in local environment, I can see 'Authenticated.'
            return response('AUTHENTICATED');
        } else {
            // in dusk, i can see 'Not Authenticated.'
            return response('Not Authenticated.');
        }
    }
}
```

#### Dusk

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use App\User;

class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testLogin()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {

            $user = Factory(User::class)->create();
            
            $str_id = $user->str_id;
            $password = config('app.guest_password');
            
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->waitFor('#user-id')
                    ->type('user-id', $str_id)
                    ->type('password', $password)
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->waitFor('#message');
        });
    }
}
```

### Setting file

#### .env

web (APP_URL) is container name of nginx

```
APP_URL=http://web

SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=****_test
DB_USERNAME=****_test
DB_PASSWORD=*********

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

#### phpunit.dusk.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Browser Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Browser</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="file"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

#### DuskTestCase.php

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    public static function prepare()
    {
        // static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions())->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--enable-file-cookies',
        ]);

        // I use Docker, container name is chrome.
        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://chrome:4444',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,
                $options
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set session driver to file

I have file phpunit.dusk.xml in the root of my app and in php section

```
<server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="file"/>
```

Try in DuskTestCase class in method `driver()` set option '--enable-file-cookies'

```
$options = (new ChromeOptions())->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--enable-file-cookies',
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
But I cannot solve this problem now also.

If you have any ideas, could you tell me them?

Comment: @keciek3 Why in prepare() you have disabled `// static::startChromeDriver();`? Also try to check if SESSION_DOMAIN is same as your backend (API endpoint) hostname, and starts with dot `.my-back-end.com`

Comment: I comment out it because I use selenium/standalone-chrome with docker referring to [document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#using-other-browsers). I understand SESSION_DOMAIN is wrong but I cannot know how to fix...  I tried SESSION_DOMAIN=app (.app, chrome, .chrome, .web and web) but it doesn"t work. Here, app is php-fpm, chrome is selenium, web is nginx container name.

Comment: I solved this problem by SESSION_DOMAIN=web, SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=web, SESSION_DRIVER=cookie.  Your advice helps me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @keciek3 SESSION_DOMAIN is domain where your laravel app sits. For example laravel app is on test.local domain, SESSION_DOMAIN should be .test.local.